# Mapping ActiveSync messages to Graph ListMessages response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Is there any documented way to map a message response from Exchange Active Sync to message response from Microsoft Graph?

Currently I'm writing some custom code and mapping them locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange Active Sync and Microsoft Graph are two different implementations. Some of the concepts between the two are similar. In general you will need to carefully look over the graph response and adjust the custom code to meet that requirement.